# Java OpenCV imread hangs when trying to read a newly written file

Tags: java, spring, maven, opencv

I'm trying to create a distributed image processor using Java Spring, OpenCV and maven. The problem I am having is when I'm trying to read the image from disk to split it up `imread` hangs completely.

I have the following maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1-2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here I am saving the incoming image(s) to disk. I can see that the directory and file is saved correctly when calling this endpoint with the image attached.

```
    @RequestMapping(path="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> postWorkOrder(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile[] files) {
        LOGGER.info("Got request containing " + files.length + " files");

        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();

        for(MultipartFile file : files) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                inputStream.read(buffer);

                File dir = new File(id+File.separator);

                if(!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdir();
                }

                File target = new File(id+File.separator+file.getOriginalFilename());
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(target);
                outputStream.write(buffer);
                fileNames.add(id+File.separator+file.getOriginalFilename());
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        executor.execute(() -> central.process(id, fileNames));

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body("/status/" + id);
    }
```

When I'm trying to read them again, nothing happens. The call to `imread` hangs! I.e the second info log is never printed. It doesn't matter if I use the absolute or relative path.

```
    public List<byte[]> split(String fileName) {
        LOGGER.info(fileName);

        Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imread(fileName);

        int height = mat.height();
        int width = mat.width();
        int SIZE = 100;
        List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

        LOGGER.info("split: " + mat.dump());

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x += SIZE) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y += SIZE) {
                Rect newRect = new Rect(x, y, SIZE, SIZE);
                Mat newMat = new Mat(mat, newRect);
                MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
                Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", newMat, matOfByte);

                list.add(matOfByte.toArray());
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

I am able to `imwrite` an empty image and read it back with `imread`.

The following are logs from the console. Note that "split: [...]" is never printed.

```
2022-09-28 15:18:05.215  INFO 26324 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.u.c.a.d.n.controller.ClientController  : Got request containing 1 files
2022-09-28 15:18:05.217  INFO 26324 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] s.u.c.a.d.n.controller.ClientController  : Starting processing
2022-09-28 15:18:05.218  INFO 26324 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] s.u.c.a.d.n.controller.ClientController  : a7ee774f-e933-4a44-a84f-08d226eb77e2\gull.jpg
```